# Router & Modem OR Modem/Router Hybrid?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, modem

I've had a lot of conflict with my ISP for getting proper speeds. After having the service line checked directly I realized that there are no problems with my ISPs services nor with any of their systems running to my home. The problem with my speeds seems to be my router/modem hybrid--which I've had multiple different models and have always had this problem. On both wireless and Ethernet the connection occasionally drops or the speeds dip altogether.

The big argument I've seen against hybrids is that they provide less processing power--missing an extra chip(processor)--which might be why the speed might be going down if the system has too large of a workload.

So which is better, getting some high end modem/router hybrid or a high end split router and modem?

Service Plan: 100mb/s.

- Average Down Speed: 50mb/s (wireless), 130mb/s (Ethernet).
- Average Up Speed: 10mb/s (wireless/Ethernet)
- Average Ping: 8ms.

This hybrid is compatible with all my devices. My current hybrid: Netgear C6300BD (Docsis 3.0)

Comment: What type of service is it?

Comment: The service runs over a coaxial cable running from my ISP's service box.

Answer (score 1):

Modem and router would probably be the best and the safest way to go. A hybrid will probably have less power than the usual router. That's bad because if you don't have good speed your internet will be really slow. Having a separate router would be better because it is specifically designed to deal with home networking. It's like taking two peoples jobs and giving it to one person and that person needs to multitask. The person gets tired and he can only do each job so much to some extent. Rather if you had two different people and they we're both doing two separate jobs those people can focus mainly on their part.

Second sometimes ISPs do not allow people to buy a separate modem. So is more safer to go with a router and a modem so just in case if the hybrid is not supported. Although the ISP  cannot control which router you have so you can get any router in the world and the ISP will have no say about it.

There is a new Stack Exchange site called hardware recommendations, maybe you should post this question on there